# How to build 3D environment in android?

Tags: android, 3d

I have developed a few simple android apps. I want to build apps and games with 3D environment. For eg [Like this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemustech.reginapro). Kindly tell me how to get started? I have not developed anything in 3D.

Comment: Check out processing. It's an extension of java that makes graphics a little easier. It can compile to android apps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the first thing you'll need is to learn about [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) and learn to use it in [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Many people use [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).  It has the benefit of also working on other platforms.

Comment: Can this be learned faster than opengl ? It will be nice if you could point to any good tutorial ?